# toggling a mouseenter event

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, bodymovin

I have an animation using bodymovin that triggers when I mouseenter it and I'm trying to make it so that if I mouseover it again before the animation ends, it doesn't restart.

```
squareAnim.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(){
anim.removeEventListener('loopComplete', loopHandler);
anim.goToAndStop(1);
anim.play();

if(anim.play == true){
    anim.mouseenter == false;
} else {
    anim.mouseenter == true;
}
});
```

Am I getting the syntax wrong or is there a flaw in my logic?

Comment: can you please add the working example on snippet here or on jsfiddle link?

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the animation is playing before you call `goToAndStop()` and `play()`:

```
squareAnim.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(){
  anim.removeEventListener('loopComplete', loopHandler);

  if(anim.play !== true){
    anim.goToAndStop(1);
    anim.play();
  }
});
```